How to Get Azure OpenAI Service to Return Document-Specific Answers Using Azure Search with typescript?
I have implemented a chat/help application in Angular using Azure OpenAI Service. The application is intended to function as an AI chatbot that performs document-based searches using Azure AI Search and OpenAI models. The documents are uploaded to SharePoint, and I am using an Azure OpenAI index to link to these documents.
The problem I'm facing is that the chatbot provides generic responses rather than specific information from the documents. For example, when I ask how to create an item in my system, it gives a general answer about creating items in e-commerce websites, whereas the specific instructions are available in the SharePoint documents.I have followed this Microsoft blog
to create this - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/azure/openai-readme?view=azure-node-preview
Here is the relevant code for my implementation:
Component Type Definitions:
export type CopilotMessageType = 'USER' | 'COPILOT';

export class CopilotMessage {
  messageType: CopilotMessageType = 'COPILOT';
  content: string = '';
}

Component Implementation:
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { BlOpenAiCopilotService } from './bl-open-ai-copilot.service';
import { CopilotMessage } from './copilot-message.model';

export class CopilotBlComponent implements OnInit {
  messageList: CopilotMessage[] = [];
  message: string = '';
  isLoading: boolean = false;
  indexName: string = '************';

  constructor(
    private copilotService: BlOpenAiCopilotService,
    private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.copilotService.configureService(this.indexName);
  }

  async sendMessage() {
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.scrollToBottom();
    this.messageList.push({ messageType: 'USER', content: this.message } as CopilotMessage);
    let currentCopilotMessageIndex = this.messageList.length - 1;
    let assistantMessageIndex: any = null;

    this.copilotService.chat(this.messageList).subscribe({
      next: (response) => {
        if (response) {
          this.isLoading = false;
          if (assistantMessageIndex === null || assistantMessageIndex < currentCopilotMessageIndex) {
            assistantMessageIndex = this.messageList.length;
            this.messageList.push({ messageType: 'COPILOT', content: response });
          } else {
            this.messageList[assistantMessageIndex].content += response;
          }
          this.scrollToBottom();
        }
      },
      complete: () => {
        this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
      },
      error: (err) => {
        console.error(err);
        this.isLoading = false;
      }
    });

    this.message = '';
  }

  scrollToBottom() {
    // Scroll to bottom logic
  }
}

Service Implementation:
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { OpenAIClient, AzureKeyCredential } from '@azure/openai';
import { Observable, from } from 'rxjs';
import { CopilotMessage } from './copilot-message.model';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class BlOpenAiCopilotService {
  private readonly _apiBase: string = '**************';
  private readonly _apiKey: string = '*************';
  private readonly _deploymentId: string = '**********';
  private readonly _searchEndpoint: string = '******************';
  private readonly _searchKey: string = '****************';
  private _client!: OpenAIClient;
  private _searchConfig!: AzureSearchChatExtensionConfiguration;
  private _chatCompletionsOptions!: GetChatCompletionsOptions;
  private _indexName: string = '';

  configureService(indexName: string): void {
    this._indexName = indexName;
    this._client = new OpenAIClient(this._apiBase, new AzureKeyCredential(this._apiKey));
    this._searchConfig = {
      type: 'azure_search',
      endpoint: this._searchEndpoint,
      authentication: { type: 'api_key', key: this._searchKey },
      indexName: this._indexName,
      strictness: 3,
      topNDocuments: 3,
    } as AzureSearchChatExtensionConfiguration;

    this._chatCompletionsOptions = {
      deploymentName: this._deploymentId,
      maxTokens: 800,
      temperature: 0,
      azureExtensionsOptions: {
        extensions: [this._searchConfig],
      },
    } as GetChatCompletionsOptions;
  }

  async *chatGenerator(messages: CopilotMessage[]): AsyncIterable<string | null> {
    let requestMessages: ChatRequestMessageUnion[] = [];

    for (const msg of messages) {
      let req: ChatRequestMessageUnion;
      if (msg.messageType === 'USER') {
        req = { role: 'user', content: msg.content };
      } else {
        req = { role: 'system', content: msg.content };
      }
      requestMessages.push(req);
    }

    const events = await this._client.streamChatCompletions(this._deploymentId, requestMessages, this._chatCompletionsOptions);

    for await (const event of events) {
      for (const choice of event.choices) {
        const delta = choice.delta?.content;
        if (delta !== undefined) {
          yield delta;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  chat(messages: CopilotMessage[]): Observable<string | null> {
    return from(this.chatGenerator(messages));
  }
}

Issue:
Despite setting up the service to use the Azure OpenAI index for document linking, the responses are not specific to the documents but are rather generic. For example, when asking about specific procedures in our system, the answers are generalized to e-commerce scenarios instead of the details in the SharePoint documents.
What I've Tried:

Ensured that the document search index is correctly set up and linked
in the Azure portal.

Verified that the documents are properly uploaded and indexed in
SharePoint.

Configured the search parameters (e.g., strictness, topNDocuments) to
narrow down the search results.


Question:
How can I make sure the Azure OpenAI Service returns specific answers from the SharePoint documents? Are there any additional configurations or steps I need to follow to achieve document-specific responses?
Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

How you configured the index with SharePoint. check you index results the data for  any query
